# Pine script divergence why is it always late?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

i found multiples script on divergence but each times there is a latency of fews candle. The thing is that in every definition of what a divergence is (on the macd for exemple) there is no such thing about waiting the confirmation of the divergence. See the code below plot divergence but 5 candles later (you can see that with the replay mode) I would like to know why. Thanks for yours answers.

````
study(title="MACD Divergences ",  resolution="")
// Getting inputs

fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", type=input.integer, defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", type=input.integer, defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
signal_length = input(title="Signal Smoothing", type=input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input(title="Oscillator MA Type", type=input.string, defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input(title="Signal Line MA Type", type=input.string, defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", input.color, group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", input.color, group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src, fast_length) : ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src, slow_length) : ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? sma(macd, signal_length) : ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)


donttouchzero = input(title="Don't touch the zero line?", defval=true)

lbR = input(title="Pivot Lookback Right", defval=5)
lbL = input(title="Pivot Lookback Left", defval=5)
rangeUpper = input(title="Max of Lookback Range", defval=60)
rangeLower = input(title="Min of Lookback Range", defval=5)
plotBull = input(title="Plot Bullish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = false
plotBear = input(title="Plot Bearish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = false
bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
hiddenBullColor = color.new(color.green, 80)
hiddenBearColor = color.new(color.red, 80)
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)
osc = macd

plFound = na(pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish
// Osc: Higher Low

oscHL = osc[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1]) and  osc[lbR] < 0

// Price: Lower Low

priceLL = low[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
priceHHZero =  highest(osc, lbL+lbR+5) 
//plot(priceHHZero,title="priceHHZero",color=color.green)
blowzero = donttouchzero ? priceHHZero < 0 : true
bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound and blowzero

plot(
     plFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bullish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     bullCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bullish Label",
     text=" Bull ",
     style=shape.labelup,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bullColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bullish
// Osc: Lower Low

oscLL = osc[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Higher Low

priceHL = low[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
hiddenBullCond = plotHiddenBull and priceHL and oscLL and plFound

plot(
     plFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bullish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(hiddenBullCond ? hiddenBullColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     hiddenBullCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bullish Label",
     text=" H Bull ",
     style=shape.labelup,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bullColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bearish
// Osc: Lower High

oscLH = osc[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])  and osc[lbR] > 0

priceLLZero =  lowest(osc, lbL+lbR+5) 
//plot(priceLLZero,title="priceLLZero", color=color.red)
bearzero = donttouchzero ? priceLLZero > 0 : true


// Price: Higher High

priceHH = high[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound and bearzero

plot(
     phFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bearish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(bearCond ? bearColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     bearCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bearish Label",
     text=" Bear ",
     style=shape.labeldown,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bearColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bearish
// Osc: Higher High

oscHH = osc[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Lower High

priceLH = high[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

hiddenBearCond = plotHiddenBear and priceLH and oscHH and phFound

plot(
     phFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bearish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(hiddenBearCond ? hiddenBearColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     hiddenBearCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bearish Label",
     text=" H Bear ",
     style=shape.labeldown,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bearColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )
     
     

alertcondition(bullCond, title="Bull", message="Regular Bull Div {{ticker}} XXmin")
alertcondition(bearCond, title="Bear", message="Regular Bear Div {{ticker}} XXmin")
alertcondition(hiddenBullCond, title="H Bull", message="Hidden Bull Div {{ticker}} XXmin")
alertcondition(hiddenBearCond, title="H Bear", message="Hidden Bear Div {{ticker}} XXmin")```
````

Answer (score 1):

Because it checks Right 5 pivots and Left 5 pivots . If you change Pivot Right to 1 it will give earlier but not reliable like 5